# One word to question whether morning or evening

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

How do you ask a question for which the answer is `morning` or `evening`, what word do you use? For example, If an employee is taking half a day leave, how do you ask which half it is? Is the following appropriate?

> **Employee:** I wish to take half a day off
>
> **Boss:** Which half of the day?

instead of

> **Employee:** I wish to take half a day off
>
> **Boss:** Morning or Evening?

The purpose of the word I am looking for is to make it a field name in the database such that it is not awkward like `[MorningOrEvening]` but at the same time it is contextually relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AM/PM (AMPM) could be an alternative although it is not a single word replacement.

Comment: Thank you, I guess that is the best solution, I've decided to use *AM/PM* for user interface and `[MorningEvening]` for the database. I did not want to use `AMPM` for the database because it could be misinterpreted as an abbreviation for something else.